Intersection of all the point exclusion topologies on a finite set having 2 or more distinct points is the indiscrete topology.
Okay, so I was thinking about point exclusion topologies and suddenly I thought about this. I sat down with pen and paper and proved this. Any suggestions are welcome. Is the part where I proved that singletons are neither open nor closed irreverent for proving this statement?
Let X be a set with 2 or more distinct elements.
Let $X=\{x_{1},...., x_{n}\}$
Let $T_{1},....,T_{n}$ be the corresponding point exclusion topologies on X.
Now, $T_{1}\cap ....\cap T_{n}$ is also a topology on X, since any number of topologies on X intersect to form another topology.
In $T_{k}$ the singleton containing $x_{k}$ is not open; for every natural number k from 1 to n.
Now, in $T_{1}\cap....\cap T_{n}$, none of the singletons are open.
Also, the complement of every $\{x_{k}\}$ is open in $T_{k}$ but not in any other point exclusion topology.
So, none of the singletons is closed in $T_{1}\cap...\cap T_{n}$
Now, none of the singletons is neither open nor closed in $T_{1} \cap....\cap T_{n}$
Let there be a non-empty proper subset U of X open in $T_{1} \cap....\cap T_{n}$
So, there exists some $x_{l}$ in U but not $x_{m}$ in U; where $x_{l}$ and $x_{m}$ are distinct points in X.
Hence, U is open in $T_{m}$ but not in $T_{l}$ and so U is not open in $T_{1}\cap...\cap T_{n}$
This is a contradiction so we know that $T_{1}\cap...\cap T_{n}$  is the indiscrete topology on X.

What is your question? Are you asking for a proof verification?

Yes, I am asking for proof verification.

Yes, your proof is correct. Also, some remarks:

Indeed, checking that any singleton is neither open or closed can be ommited. The only relevant part is the last four lines of your proof.
This statement can be also generalized for any arbitrary set.


Let $X$ be an arbitrary set with at lest two different elements. For all $x\in X$, denote $\mathcal{T}_x$ the point exclusion topology of $x$. Then, $\bigcap_{x\in X}\mathcal{T}_x$ is the indiscrete topology.

Proof: It is analogous to your proof mutatis mutandis. The arbitrary interesction of topologies is also a topology. Now, suppose that $\varnothing\neq U\subsetneq X$. There exists some $x_0\in X$ such that $x_0\in U$. Hence, we have that $U\notin \mathcal{T}_{x_0}$, implying that $U\notin\bigcap_{x\in X} \mathcal{T}_x$. $\square$

Thanks a lot. I have proved an even more interesting thing. The union of all point exclusion topologies on X is also a topology, infact the discrete topology.

It also occurs the same with the particular point topology: given $p\in X$, $U\in\mathcal{T}_p\Leftrightarrow p\in U$. The intersection of all of them is the indicrete, whereas the union is the discrete. And this is natural: intersecting many topologies gives rise to a really coarse topology and, on the other hand, the union of topologies (although generally is not a topology) is much finer. In this case, we operate with enough intersections and unions to reach the coarsest and the finest possible topologies defined on a set.

Fix $i$. In $T_i$, $x_i$'s singleton isn't open. Therefore no point's singleton is open in all $T_k$. Also complements of singletons fail in at least one $T_k$. Hence only $X$ and $\emptyset$ remain open in the intersection. That intersection is the indiscrete topology.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
